# I use netbeans and i want to run my PHP application,i have installed xampp and wampserver in my machine

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

I want to run complete my assignment using wampserver but it returns the error as below 
"#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.— The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)."

Comment: XAMPP and WAMPServer are basically the same thing. Most importantly they both have an Apache and both those Apache servers use port 80 by default. As XAMPP probably autostarts Apache, when you boot the PC, XAMPP-Apache starts and  grabs port 80, so when you start WAMPServers-Apache it cannot use port 80 as its already allocated. I suggest you Uninstall XAMPP. ___After backing up any web site code AND databases you want to keep, that currently exists in the XAMPP env___

Comment: Alternatively, STOP XAMPP Apache and XAMPP MySQL Server and then you will be able to use WAMPServer's Apache and MySQL Servers

Answer (score 0):

It seems u are trying to make connection without starting ur server: 

1. Open xampp application.

2. Start the service for Apache and Mysql.

3. Then open your browser and put localhost link in the address bar, it will open and 
 says welcome to XAMPP.

[image]

Comment: but whenI start i get the following errors  5:03:58 AM  [Apache]  Problem detected!
5:03:58 AM  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by ""c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 6764!
5:03:58 AM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
5:03:58 AM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
5:03:58 AM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: OP says they want to use WAMPServer, so it would be simpler to just Uninstall XAMPP so the 2 Apache servers and the 2 MySQL servers are not both fighting for the same TCP ports